# Alternative of Jrebel for Hotswap or HotDeployment in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jrebel, hotdeploy

As i am working in **Java** from past couple of year i do not saw any effort from Oracle   to solve the problem of **class reloading**. 
Like done by [Jrebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/)

But its a licensed version and cost is very high its very worthy for me to buy 10-20 developer license.
Any one know any open source or less costly licensing product which i can use for **Hot deployment** of Java classes as like JSPs OR JSF  so i do not need to restart the server again and again for small Java class change.

Right now i am using **Eclipse IDE** ,Is any other Open source IDE like **NetBeans** have this inbuild feature or plugin available ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class reloading alone does not solve JSP or JSF or any other framework configuration reloading. This is what JRebel offers beyond class reloading.

You can make a search on the same topic in StackOverflow or Google and you'll find plenty of questions like your own. None of the alternatives are at the same level. You may take a look at [Play! Framework](http://www.playframework.com/), for instance, but that will require you to change the technology stack for your current project.

Comment: Do you mean no any good alternatives ?

Comment: The definition of "good" is quite different depending on the context. See the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/17642585/431270

Answer (score 21):

Take a look at [Hotswap Agent](https://github.com/HotswapProjects/HotswapAgent):

- Framework support - Spring, Hibernate, Logback, Jetty, Tomcat, JSF, ...
- Documentation how to setup DCEVM and precompiled binaries for Java 1.7
- Load classes and resources from various location (allow reload of classes from dependent project]
- Open source and free

Comment: Sweeeeeet this looks promising i have my fingers crossed